# Boolean method to check a random number

Tags: java, random, int, boolean, type-conversion

I have a class that generates a random number within a given interval.

```
    public class Dice{
          //code.....

          public int throwDice(){
             Random randomGen = new Random();
             int min = 1;
             int max = sides; //sides gets a value earlier in the class
             int randomNum = randomGen.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
             return randomNum;
          }
```

Then the assignment says that I'm going to use a `boolean` method that looks like this (with my already written code in it as well):

```
    private boolean step(){
        int res = this.dice.throwDice();
        int startpos = this.bridge.getFirst();
        if (res == 10){ //this works
            return false;
        }
        else if (res => 7 && res <= 9 ){ //but the error occurs here 
            //code....
            return true;
        }
```

What I need to do is check if the generated random number in the `throwDice()` method is within a certain interval of numbers.

The problem is that I get an error that says that I can't convert an `int` to a `boolean`. Is there a way to get around this? Or do I have to rethink my whole solution?

Comment: Please share your code and show exactly which row generates this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=>` should be the other way around.

```
else if (res => 7 && res <= 9 ){
```

should be

```
else if (res >= 7 && res <= 9 ){
```

Equality and Relational Operators

```
==      Equal to
!=      Not equal to
>       Greater than
>=      Greater than or equal to <-----
<       Less than
<=      Less than or equal to
```

[Source Equality and Relational Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Comment: Thanks, i must have overlooked it and tought it was something completely different. Such a small thing!

Comment: @TNT I added more info to your awesome answer for better clarity. hope it is ok with you :)